# Hide questions with ignored tags in Favorite Tags filter

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags, tag-filters, tag-watching

My favourite page on Stack Exchange is [/filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters), which by default shows the "Favorite Tags" built-in filter. This filter is great, because it includes all favourite/"watched" tags on all sites, including SO. However, it does not take into account the ignored tags on those sites.

Use case: I know and use Bash but I use Windows only rarely, so [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is one of my favourite tags and [tag:windows*] is one of my ignored tags. Now if someone asks a question tagged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *and* [windows-subsystem-for-linux](/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux), some people will want to see that question (which is how it works now) and some people will *not* want to see that question (waves hands awkwardly).

If this is how it already works, and some things with ignored tags show up in my list because their tags have been changed since they were added to the feed that's totally fine; I expect trimming that list after edits would be quite expensive. If there's already a setting for this I'm sorry for the noise.